# Tinted background image not working with Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I added a black transparent gradient to my body background image, but when I add bootstrap to the html file, it stops working.

```css
body {
    background: 
      linear-gradient(
        rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5), 
        rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)
      ),
      url("https://picsum.photos/id/1000/800/800");
      background-size: cover;
  }
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

Comment: I have tried your code, only text color is changing when you add bootstarp

Comment: you only need `html{height:100%;}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Follow the example given in this link -> https://mdbootstrap.com/docs/jquery/css/background-image/

HTML

```
<body>

<div class="bg"></div>

<p class="py-5 text-center">This example creates a full page background image. Try to resize the browser window to see how it always will cover the full screen (when scrolled to top), and that it scales nicely on all screen sizes.</p>
```

CSS

```
body, html {
  height: 100%;
}
.bg {
  /* The image used */
  background-image: url("https://mdbootstrap.com/img/Photos/Horizontal/Nature/full page/img(20).jpg");

  /* Full height */
  height: 100%;

  /* Center and scale the image nicely */
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}
```